# NullPointerException while trying to run my CodenameOne projects on Simulator

Tags: javafx, codenameone

I started getting below error message today while trying to test my app on Simulator.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1090)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaFXLoader.restartJVM(JavaFXLoader.java:322)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaFXLoader.runWithJavaFX(JavaFXLoader.java:276)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaFXLoader.main(JavaFXLoader.java:287)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor.main(Executor.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator.main(Simulator.java:106)
```

I have reinstalled CodenameOne Netbeans plugin, reinstalled Netbeans 11.2, upgrade my JDK to 13.0.1, cleared netbeans and codenameone caches, restarted computer severally but cannot still get the Simulator working.

Running on Windows 10

Comment: Can you show your code? Especially the `Simulator` class.

Comment: @dan1st Simulator is not a Class, Chibuike Mba is referring to: https://www.codenameone.com/codename-one-simulator.html

Answer (score 0):

We don't support JDKs newer than 11 and don't support JDK 9/10. Only Oracle JDK 8 (possibly ZuluFX 8) and any type of JDK 11 (Oracle/OpenJDK etc.).

So JDK 13 isn't supported yet. Oracle just breaks them freely with every release now.

Comment: @shai_almog, the issue started with Oracle JDK 11, in my quest to fix the issue I installed Oracle JDK 13 but it didn't work. Everything was ok with my JDK 11 for months now, I worked on one of our codenameone projects on Thursday till I closed work for the day, coming to work on Friday to resume from where I stopped the issue started.

Comment: We're pushing out a new update today that should solve this regression

Comment: The update have solved that issue for me. Thanks Shai.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I believe it started when I "Updated the Project Libs". In NetBeans, this is via right click on the project - Codename One - Codename One Settings - Basic - Update Project Libs. I believe the latest version of JavaSE.jar is causing the problem. My workaround (not a permanent fix) is to revert to an earlier version of the file. Hope this helps.